How to prevent Kendo UI input components from being focused when browser autofill is triggered in Angular?
I am working on an Angular application that uses Kendo UI components like kendo-textbox, kendo-combobox, and kendo-datepicker. The issue I am facing is that whenever the browser autofill feature is triggered (for example, when filling in the form with saved credentials or address), all input fields (textboxes, comboboxes, and datepickers) get focused automatically.
I want to prevent the Kendo UI input components from being focused when the browser's autofill feature is triggered. Currently, all fields become focused simultaneously, which is not the expected behavior.
Question: Is there a way to prevent the Kendo UI inputs from being focused when the browser autofill is triggered in an Angular app? Are there any workarounds or specific settings that need to be adjusted in Kendo UI or the Angular component code to handle this?
Any suggestions or workarounds would be appreciated!
